# ListView: Selector drawables drawn in different sizes

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I'm using a custom ListView selector.
Everything works fine, except that the drawables for state_focused and state_pressed 
are drawn bigger than the normal state.

Instead of the default implementation, which uses 9-patch bitmaps, I'm using ShapeDrawables. They all use the same padding values (see below)
It seems, that they're overwritten by some other values.
Probably a theme? Couldn't find it though.

ListView

```
<ListView
style="@style/dark_bg_style"
android:id="@android:id/list"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_margin="10dp"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
android:layoutAnimation="@anim/list_layout_in"
android:scrollbars="none"
android:divider="#00000000"
android:dividerHeight="5dp"
android:listSelector="@drawable/list_sel"
/>
```

list_sel.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" android:state_window_focused="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_bg_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_bg_focused" android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_bg_focused" android:state_focused="true"/>
</selector>
```

excerpt from list element layout

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="@drawable/menu_sel"
  >
...
```

menu_sel.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" 
        android:state_focused="true" 
        android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_bg_normal"/>
</selector>
```

button_bg_normal.xml

```
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid
        android:color="#44C8C8C8" />
    <corners
        android:radius="5sp" />
    <padding
        android:left="10dip"
        android:top="5dip"
        android:right="10dip"
        android:bottom="5dip" />
</shape>
```

button_bg_pressed.xml

```
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid
        android:color="#77C8C8C8" />
    <corners
        android:radius="5sp" />
    <padding
        android:left="10dip"
        android:top="5dip"
        android:right="10dip"
        android:bottom="5dip" />
</shape>
```

button_bg_focused.xml

```
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid
        android:color="#44C8C8C8" />
    <corners
        android:radius="5sp" />
    <stroke
        android:color="#55FFFFFF"
        android:width="1dip" />
    <padding
        android:left="10dip"
        android:top="5dip"
        android:right="10dip"
        android:bottom="5dip" />

</shape>
```

Answer (score 2):

When working with `ListView`s, it is better to set the background states as the `android:listSelector`. In your code, there is a contention between the states in `android:listSelector` and the `android:background` specified for the individual row.